# Extension attribute 'neighborhood' not working when payment method is PayPal standard

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, paypal, custom-attributes, extension-attributes

I have added an extension attribute via

**extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="neighborhood" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="reference" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="neighborhood" type="string"/>
        <attribute code="reference" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

It shows up when using other payment methods such as OpenPay, I can even see it when making a mock order (extension attribute is at the bottom):

[image: Request Payload]

Does anyone know if the process to read that attribute is any different when using PayPal as a payment method?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing similar situation.. How did you fix this issue ?

Comment: Could you share the solution it will be helpful for me'

Comment: @aravind I couldn't find a solution using PayPal directly, so what I did was create another table in the database and 'bridge' the custom attributes with it.
1. Write the custom attribute in a new table when generating the order.
2. Retrieve it from there when necessary.
Sorry I can't be clearer now, the actual code is at the office and I've been working from home.

Comment: Sure thanks for your help @Franco